# Access to DOM body element from within Angular TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

We use the standard Jasmine/Angular unit test setup for our component unit tests, using

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
```

inside of the beforeEach method.

Most of the time, we have no problems accessing elements using

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('myelement'));
```

But every once in a while, we want to test the behavior of a bit of UI that is actually appended to the html body.  For example, we're using a bespoke dialog service that we call from within 'MyComponent', and want to verify that it was properly loaded with the correct contents.  (I know you could argue that it's outside the scope of the 'MyComponent' unit test, but let's just assume that we need to do it this way.)

When I try

```
const allHTML = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('*'));
```

I can see that Angular is only giving my the contents of 'MyComponent' and not the entire DOM.  So, because of this, I have no way of accessing elements that may be appended to the body.

Has anyone found a way to test with this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native element's [`ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/ownerDocument) property to navigate to the whole document, then call `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` on the document.

```
let doc = fixture.nativeElement.ownerDocument;
doc.querySelectorAll("myelement");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html id="main">
```

```
// in beforeEach: create above code via createElement and setAttribute
const dummyElement = document.createElement('html');
dummyElement.setAttribute('id', 'main');
document.getElementById = jasmine.createSpy('HTML Element').and.returnValue(dummyElement);
```

```
const main = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('main');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this only gives me an empty html element.  It doesn't allow me to access UI elements that are appended to the html body, since the DOM returned in the fixture.debugElement queries only includes everything within my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can access whole DOM of the page by querying on native component associated with your fixture.

```
       let myComponentNative = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

        let parent : HTMLElement = myComponentNative;
        while( parent.parentElement) {
            // you can inspect on the tag name to actually stop at particular tag, for example you might want to go up until you reach "body"
            console.log(parent.tagName); 

            parent = parent.parentElement;
        }

        const elemUnderParent = parent.querySelectorAll("myelement");

        // you can print the contents of your dom as well
        console.log(parent.innerHTML);
```